# Is there anyway I can get the position of img tag? In python using beautifulsoup find function

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy, screen-scraping

I would like to know at what position of the td tag the .png image file lies.

For example, in this case (row 5) is there any way I can get the position of the image tag? In python using beautifulsoup to find the function or scrappy?

```
</tr>
            <tr id="table_1_row_3">
                <td style="">A List</td>
                                                    <td style=""></td>
                                                    <td style="">Itemnumber</td>
                                                    <td style="">price</td>
                                                    <td style=""></td>
                                                    <td style=""><img src='https://www.example.com/.png' /></td>
                                                    <td style=""></td>
                                                    <td style=""></td>
                                                    <td style=""></td>
                                                    <td style=""></td>
                                                    <td style=""></td>
                                                    <td style=""></td>
                                                    <td style=""></td>
                                                    <td style=""></td>
                                                    <td style="">min price<BR>a List<BR></td>
                                                    <td style=""></td>
                                                    <td style=""></td>
                                                    <td style=""></td>
                                                    <td style=""></td>
                                                    <td style=""></td>
                                                    <td style=""></td>
                                                    <td style=""></td>
                                                    <td style=""></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use built-in function `enumerate()` for the task:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''
    <tr id="table_1_row_3">
        <td style="">A List</td>
        <td style=""></td>
        <td style="">Itemnumber</td>
        <td style="">price</td>
        <td style=""></td>
        <td style=""><img src='https://www.example.com/.png' /></td>
        <td style=""></td>
        <td style=""></td>
        <td style=""></td>
        <td style=""></td>
        <td style=""></td>
        <td style=""></td>
        <td style=""></td>
        <td style=""></td>
        <td style="">min price<BR>a List<BR></td>
        <td style=""></td>
        <td style=""></td>
        <td style=""></td>
        <td style=""></td>
        <td style=""></td>
        <td style=""></td>
        <td style=""></td>
        <td style=""></td>
    </tr>'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

# find all positions of <img> inside <tr>:
idx = [i for i, td in enumerate(soup.select('tr > td')) if td.img]

# print indexes, where there is <img> inside <td>:
print(idx)
```

Prints:

```
[5]
```